# Pass Variable to CLLocationManager in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

How can I pass the instance of `avg` to:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
```

Function below? I want to take the average of the array and then submit it to an external database when the location updates.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    // Make Manager Delegate & Set Accuracy
    manager.delegate = self;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    // Call Timer
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(arrayBuild)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES];
    // Initialise Array
    resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

- (void)arrayBuild {

    loopCount++;

    if (loopCount >= 11) {

        // Find Average
        NSNumber *avg = [resultsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];

        // Change Text of Label to Average & Log
        self.signal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",avg];
        NSLog(@"%@",avg);
        // I want to send this value here ^^ to the didUpdateLocation function

        // Update Location
        [manager startUpdatingLocation];

        // Invalidate Timer
        [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer = nil;

    }else{

        // Declare Signal Strength
        float signalstrength = CTGetSignalStrength();

        // Individual Result & Convert to Integer
        NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", signalstrength];
        NSInteger resultInt = [result integerValue];

        // Add Object
        [resultsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:resultInt]];

        // Change Text of Label Each Second
        self.signal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",loopCount];
        NSLog(@"%f",signalstrength);
    }
}

#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"Failed to get location!");

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"Location: %@",newLocation);
    CLLocation *curentLocation = newLocation;

    if (curentLocation != nil) {

        float signalstrength = CTGetSignalStrength();

        // Code below uses a third party utility to submit data
        PFObject *Object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Issue"];
        Object[@"Latitude"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        Object[@"Longitude"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        Object[@"Signal"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",signalstrength];
        [Object saveInBackground];

        // Update Text Fields
        self.latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        self.longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        self.signal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",signalstrength];
    }
    // Stop the Location Update
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

I thought it would involved [self manager:avg] or something similar? But I'm not sure exactly what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an instance variable (or property) for the average variable, that way you can calculate and set it in the arrayBuild function and have it accessible in the didUpdateLocation function.